# Combination problems with replacement

Tags: statistics, combinations

A restaurant has n items on its menu. During a particular day, k customers will arrive and each one will choose one item. The manager wants to count how many different collections of customer choices are possible without regard to the order in which the choices are made.
(For example, if k = 3 and a1,..., an are the menu items, then a1a3a1 is not distinguished from a1a1a3.) Prove that the number of different collections of customer choices is ${n+k-1 \choose k}$. Hint: Assume that the menu items are a1,..., an. Show that each collection of customer choices, arranged with the a1’s first, the a2’s second, etc., can be identified with a sequence of k zeros and n − 1 ones, where each 0 stands for a customer choice and each 1 indicates a point in the sequence where the menu item number increases by 1. For example, if k = 3 and n = 5, then a1a1a3 becomes 0011011.

I know it's a combination problem with replacement, and I remember the formula is exactly ${n+k-1 \choose k}$. But I forget how to prove it and don't understand the example of 0011011. I'll appreciate it if there is somebody offering help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is a [Stars and Bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  A proof can be found on that link.

Comment: $0011011$ is in effect $**|.|*|.|.$ where $*$ is a $0$ and $.$ is a placeholder for no $0$s.  Counting the $*$s between each bar and at the beginning and end, this represents $2$ of $a_1$, $0$ of $a_2$, $1$ of $a_3$, $0$ of $a_4$ and $0$ of $a_5$ as required: the total number of $*$s will be $k=3$ and the number of $|$s  will be $n-1=4$ to give $n=5$ potential places for $*$s.  You need to count the number of possible arrangements of stars and bars which is clearly ${k+n-1 \choose k}$ or the equal ${k+n-1 \choose n-1}$

Comment: I'm so happy that I finally figured it out. The proof was so amazing that I had no idea until I saw the process. thx for both of your help!!